# Replace empty string "" character with null in JSON body by XSLT 1.0

Tags: json, xslt, replace, null, ibm-datapower

I'm trying to remove `""` representation of empty string with null value.

For example JSON body:

```json
{
"eid":      "string"    ,
"iccid":    "string"    ,
"profileType": "",
"resultData":"" ,
"notificationPointId":      3   ,
"header": ""
}
```

Target JSON:

```json
{
"eid":      "string"    ,
"iccid":    "string"    ,
"profileType": null,
"resultData":null   ,
"notificationPointId":      3   ,
"header": null
}
```

Comment: XSLT 1.0 cannot process JSON (that is not as JSON; you could possibly process it as text - if you have a way to read it). If you are converting the JSON to IBM's JSONx format and back, please edit your question and show the input and expected output as JSONx (i.e. XML).

Comment: XSLT 1.0 can process text , if i extract the body as a text . The problem with JSONX and my goal to achieve is simple : I`m getting an input empty value as ("") , my tool can only get (null) , throwing exception . Transformation to jsonx will give me as example :                 <json:string name="resultData"/> . As i understand your sugestion will be to transform JSONX to json with null on empty string and not ""

Comment: I am afraid you misunderstood me. XSLT 1.0 can only process XML. I am trying to reproduce your problem. For this, I need to see your input XML. Then I want to understand what is the output you expect to get. If you want to get JSON (i.e. text) then you may be looking at a lot of work. If you want to get something that you can convert to JSON using another process, then I want to see that. Until then I am not making any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `jq` compiler like this:

```sh
jq '  .profileType = if .profileType == "" then null else .profileType end
    | .resultData  = if .resultData  == "" then null else .resultData  end
    | .header      = if .header      == "" then null else .header      end
   ' \
   empty_null.json
```

Comment: hi , thank you for quick answer . My restriction is XSLT 1.0 , on  some legacy IBM mashine .

Answer (score 0):

As you'd have to handle your JSON as string it should be doable using a standard `regexp:replace` in a DP XSLT... From your sample, e.g.:

```
<!-- Add regexp ns to the XSLT declaration, e.g: -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions"
  xmlns:regexp="http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"
  xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
  extension-element-prefixes="dp"
>

<xsl:variable name="nullJSON" 
      select="regexp:replace($str,'""','','')"/>
```

But, you should REALLY change the transform into GatewayScript if you handle JSON!